# Nonexistence of a continuous injection $f:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

What is the "easiest" way to show that there is no continuous injection $f:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$?

Sure the *Borsuk-Ulam theorem* implies that result, but this may be a "difficult" way.

Comment: @Juho One can give an easy proof in case $f$ is an immersion

Comment: Can Picard's theorem do this?

Comment: @RobertFrost I see no connection with Picard's theorem.

Comment: What about if you project $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto a sphere the x-axis requires a point at infinity and so does the y-axis and so do every combination of the two. These can't be accommodated on a single point on the sphere.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Picard's Theorem, first of all, is about complex analytic mappings. If you're going to assume complex analyticity, it will then be far more elementary, even without the injectivity assumption.

Comment: Does a continuous mapping from one space that is parallelisable to 2nd, guarantee that the 2nd is parallelisable?  This would also prove it since $S^2$ is not parallelisable.

Comment: What does parallelizable mean, @RobertFrost? You're talking tangent bundles and differentiable structures. A one-to-one continuous map is far from a diffeomorphism! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a non-obvious result. By [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), if there were such an $f$, its image would be open in $\Bbb R^2$. But it would, of course, also be compact. Oops.

Comment: This is also very intuitive result, since it is impossible to draw a one "normal map" of the whole Earth.

Comment: How does invariance of domain apply?

Comment: @ChristianSievers: You get a basis for the topology on the sphere (or, indeed, any manifold) by taking sets homeomorphic to balls in Euclidean space.

Comment: Oh, I think you should link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain#Generalizations

Comment: So the set $f(S^2)$ is always a countable union of open sets, and therefore open?

Comment: Well, by compactness, in fact a *finite* union of open sets, yes :)

Comment: OK, now I understand. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

A broad-strokes proof outline:

Consider two points $a,b \in S^2$ and a continuous closed curve $C\in S^2$ such that all coninuous transformations mapping $a\to b$ contain a value on $C$.  The existtance of such a triplet is shown by example:  The North and South poles, and the equator, on a sphere.

Now consider any continuous injection of that triplet onto some co-domain $D \in \Bbb{R}^2$.  (Since the injection is also surjective onto $D$ it is a bijection.)  Since every continuous curve line from $a$ to $b$ intersects $C$, and continuous injections preserve that property, exactly one of $a',b'$ must lie in the interior of $C'$.  Without loss of generality, say $a'$ is not in the interior of $C'$.

Then $C'$ cannot be continuously deformed to lie completely in an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$-ball containing $a'$ in its interior.  And a continous injection would preserve that property.  Yet $C$ can be continuously deformed to lie completely in an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$-ball containing $a$ in its interior.  This contradictoin shows that we could not have the desired continuous injection.

Comment: I don't understand why exactly one of $a'$ and $b'$ has to lie on the interior of $C'$.

Comment: If both are in the exterior or both in the interior, then there is a continuous curve not intersecting $C'$ that goes from $a'$ to $b'$.